# get all decimal places after division

Tags: python, floating-point, division

I have to do a calculation with `1/50000`. When I do

```
float(1/50000)
```

in python it only returns me `0.0`. How can I get the actual value in the powers in python? I would like to get `2.5*10^(-5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [2]: 1.0/50000
Out[2]: 2e-05
```

Note the `.0`. It makes sure `1.0` is a floating-point literal and not an integer one.

A different way to write this is as follows:

```
In [3]: float(1)/50000
Out[3]: 2e-05
```

What you have right now first uses integer division to compute `1/50000`. The result of this division is the integer `0`, which is then converted to a floating-point value (`0.0`).

Finally, note that your current code will behave correctly in Python 3 (and the `float()` is superfluous). This is due to [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Comment: `1./50000` is all that's really required.

Answer (score 3):

use python 3.x

```
>>> 1/50000
2e-05
```

or on python 2.x

```
>>> from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `1.0/50000` or `float(1)/50000`.  The way you did it, by the time you convert to float, the division has already been done and it's too late to get extra accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

The input arguments have to be floats to be divided as floats:

```
float(1) / float(50000)
```

Or

```
1./50000
```

The decimal casts 1 as a float. If one of the input values is a float, the division operation will get floated as well.

What you were doing was dividing integers to get 0, and then casting 0 to a float as '0.0'.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert one of the arguments to a **float**:

```
>>> 1 / float(50000)
2e-05
```